# Какие существуют стандарты для отрисовки страницы?

Tags: оптимизация

Есть ли какие-то стандарты или рекомендации по показателям загрузки страницы? Например, на вкладке Timeline у меня следующие показатели:

> - Loading: 26,0ms
> - Painting: 40,06ms
> - Rendering: 355,0ms
> - Scripting: 621,5ms

Как мне знать, хорошие ли это показатели или мне стоит оптимизировать загрузку и отображение?

Comment: хорошие показатели меньше 1 секунды

Comment: да есть рекомендации - https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/

Answer (score 2):

В целом ваши показатели можно было бы улучшить. Страница в среднем должна грузиться 1 секунду. Я бы посоветовал вам оптимизировать весь статический контент на сайте.

#### Сжатие графики

В вашем случае кроме сжатия стилей и скриптов посоветую сжимать и графику. К примеру, картинки можно легко сжать без потери качества только за счет удаление exif-данных. На реальном сайте можно сократить размер картинок в среднем на 70%, что на современном сайте равняется примерно 4 МБ. Пример на `gulp`:

```
var
    gulp = require('gulp'),
    imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),
    imageminJR = require('imagemin-jpeg-recompress'),
    imageminSvgo = require('imagemin-svgo');

// Optimizing images
gulp.task('imagemin', function() {
    gulp.src('./img/**/*')
        .pipe(imagemin([
            imageminJR({
                method: 'ms-ssim'
            }),
            imageminSvgo({
                plugins: [
                    {removeViewBox: false}
                ]
            })
        ]))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/img/'))
});
```

А для браузеров, которые понимают легковесный формат `webp` (формат разработан Google), можно сделать еще такой вариант изображений:

```
var
    gulp = require('gulp'),
    webp = require('gulp-webp');

// Generate Webp
gulp.task('webp', function() {
    gulp.src('./img/**/*')
        .pipe(webp())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/img/'))
});
```

#### Оптимизация скриптов

Сперва объедините все скрипты в один файл и минифицируйте их. Это помет сократить количество HTTP-запросов и размер файлов:

```
var
    gulp = require('gulp'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

// Concat JS
gulp.task('js', function(){
    gulp.src([
        './js/jquery.js',
        './js/wow.js',
        './js/menu.js',
        './js/scrollspy.js',
        './js/main.js',
        './js/temp/contact.bundled.js',
        './js/owl.carousel.js'
    ])
        .pipe(concat('script.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/js/'))
});
```

#### Оптимизация стилей

Кроме обычной минификации стилей можно использовать и продвинутую - объединять дубликаты классов и @media. Пример на `gulp`:

```
var
    gulp = require('gulp'),
    stylus = require('gulp-stylus'),

    // Минифицирует CSS, объединяет классы. Не ломает CSS, в отличие от cssnano, который, к примеру, может неправильно выставлять z-index
    csso = require('gulp-csso'),

    // Объединяет все @media
    cmq = require('gulp-group-css-media-queries'),

    // Сокращает CSS-селекторы    
    gs = require('gulp-selectors'),

    // Проставляет вендорные префиксы
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),

    livereload = require('gulp-livereload'),
    nib = require('nib');

// Compiling Stylus in CSS
gulp.task('css', function() {
    gulp.src('./styl/*.styl')
        .pipe(stylus({
            use: nib()
        }))
        .pipe(cmq())
        .pipe(csso())
        .pipe(autoprefixer('last 3 versions'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/css/'))
});
```

А если совсем делать нечего, то можно еще и селекторы сократить:

```
// Minify selectors
    gulp.task('gs', function() {
        var ignores = {
            classes: ['active', 'menu', 'nav', 'slide', 'error', 'form-control', 'loader', 'showLoader', 'fadeLoader', 'webp', 'wow', 'owl-*', 'i-*'],
            ids: '*'
        };
        gulp.src(['./public/**/*.css', './public/**/*.html'])
            .pipe(gs.run({}, ignores))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/'))
    });
```

Кстати, наверняка у вас есть классы, добавляющиеся через JS, поэтому предварительно стоит все такие классы вынести в переменную `ignores`.

#### Кеширование статики на стороне пользователя

Также бы посоветовал кешировать скрипты и стили на стороне пользователя, чтобы исключить их повторную загрузку, если они не изменились:

```
<FilesMatch ".(flv|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|ico|svg|swf|js|css|pdf|woff2|woff|ttf|eot)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000"
</FilesMatch>
```

И включить gzip сжатие на сервере:

```
# сжатие text, html, javascript, css, xml:
<ifModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml application/xml application/xhtml+xml text/css text/javascript application/javascript application/x-javascript
</ifModule>
```

Comment: Спасибо за большой и объёмный ответ! Gzip-сжатие у меня включено, кэширование на стороне сервера включено(Expires), изображения сжимаю при помощи [tinyjpg](https://tinyjpg.com/). Объединение стилей и js буду делать уже в продакшене. Во время разработки будет не очень удобно листать 5000 строк css-кода.

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin дело в том, что при использовании препроцессоров вы будете работать с исходными файлами, который будут удобно разбиты по вашему усмотрению. Однако компилироваться они будут в один большой.